# Visual Basic Referencing .Net Objects In An Array

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I have a big list of objects in the Design view of Visual Basic 2010 that I need to change a bunch of properties for, so of course I tried using an array rather than taking 50-60 lines for a repetitive task. But there seems to be an issue referencing to the object and it seems to be just taking the information from it. I know that was a shitty explanation, but maybe you'll understand it when you see it.

```
    Dim objectsToClear As Array = _
    {lblDailyRoundTrip, lblDaysWorked, lblFillBoxes, lblMilesPerGallon, lblMonthlyInsurance, _
     lblMonthlyMaintenance, lblMonthlyParking, tbDailyRoundTrip, tbDaysWorked, tbMilesPerGallon, _
     tbMonthlyInsurance, tbMonthlyMaintenance, tbMonthlyParking}

        For i = LBound(objectsToClear) To UBound(objectsToClear)
        objectsToClear(i).Text = ""
        objectsToClear(i).Visible = False
    Next
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
Dim objectsToClear As Array = { lblDailyRoundTrip, 
                                lblDaysWorked, 
                                lblFillBoxes, 
                                lblMilesPerGallon, 
                                lblMonthlyInsurance, 
                                lblMonthlyMaintenance, 
                                lblMonthlyParking, 
                                tbDailyRoundTrip, 
                                tbDaysWorked, 
                                tbMilesPerGallon, 
                                tbMonthlyInsurance, 
                                tbMonthlyMaintenance, 
                                tbMonthlyParking }

For Each item In objectsToClear
    item.Text = String.Empty
    item.Visible = False
Next item
```

P.S. - you REALLY should have `Option Strict On`, and you should have strongly typed your array.

Comment: Thanks, this is for a VB class I just started and the book teaches Option Strict On and other such things in the later part of the book.

Answer (score 1):

Since you seem to be interested in changing only `.Text` and `.Visible` properties, then you can just find the control by name, like this:

```
Dim returnValue As Control()
returnValue = Me.Controls.Find(objectsToClear(i), True)
```

Note: The `True` argument is for whether or not to search all children, which it sounds like you want to do. Read [Control.ControlCollection.Find Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find%28VS.80%29.aspx) documentation for more information.

Now that you have a collection of controls that match the name you specified, loop through the controls in that collection and set the property values, like this:

```
For Each c As Control In returnValue
    c.Text = ""
    c.Visible = False
Next
```

Comment: It's impossible to tell from the code he posted, but I think that the elements of `objectsToClear` might already be controls.